# I need msvcr100 symbols (internal network)

Tags: visual-c++

Need msvcr100 symbols to help debug a crash.

Working on an internal network - no access to internet symbol servers

win7(32), VS2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download Windows Symbol Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx).

Comment: Already did, unfortunately MSVCR100.PDB is not in the windows 7 symbol package.

Comment: @AmitRon, I think it might have a slightly different name. Look for msvcr100.i386.pdb, it should probably be there. You can also try to debug a similarly build app on a machine that does have access to the web, and grab the downloaded pdb from there.

Comment: I just used dumpbin  - it verified your comment. The PDB was not found because of version mismatch. Now I need to find the symbol package to match my DLL... Thank you